# Cast irregular string to integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Right now I'm working with a legacy database where one column ( foreign key ) is a nVarChar which consists of cells in form of e.g. '23 +abcde' where '23' is the actual key and the rest are some sort of attributes (?).

So what I need is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE bad_column = 23;
```

What would be the best way to cast that '23 +abc' to 23 ?

Comment: Could you change that table and add a column for just that key-int? A select that requires an expression in the `where` is fairly slow. With an extra column you get that computation just once.

Comment: Well, that would be an option, but I'm not allowed to touch the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(bad_column, 1, CHARINDEX('+', bad_column)) AS INT) = 23;
```

Comment: This was the most appropriate solution for my case.

Comment: What if no '+' is present in the string?

Comment: As I understand bad_column - is a synthetic key. So I assumed that symbol will always be in this string. In another case this: SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING('56678', 1, CHARINDEX('+', '56678')) AS INT) return zero.

Comment: Agree with your comments. However, initially requested use string format, similar to '23 +______'.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * from table_name
WHERE (CASE WHEN PatIndex('%[0-9]%', bad_column) > 0 
THEN CONVERT(INT,LEFT(bad_column,LEN(bad_column)-PatIndex('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(bad_column))+1))
ELSE 0 END) = 23
```

Comment: Thanks, this of course is a lot more general purpose, but for this case I decided to go with a bit more simplistic approach, that Devart proposed.

Answer (score 0):

To select that sort of data, you want something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE bad_column LIKE '23%';
```

This is not a cast but a conversion.

```
SELECT substring (bad_column, 1, patindex(' ', bad_column))
FROM table
WHERE bad_column LIKE '23%';
```

Comment: This will not work. It returns different rows for keys starting with 23 (23, 230, 2309, etc)

Comment: **If** there is always a space after the number, use `like '23 %'`, to prevent the situation that Barabba described.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where `<key>` = 23 in this case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE SUBSTRING(bad_column,1,LEN(<key>)) NOT LIKE '[a-zA-Z]'
AND SUBSTRING(bad_column,1,LEN(<key>)) = <key>
```

In this way no cast is required (the `NOT LIKE` clause avoids literals, you must provide other chars rules) while comparing and you're sure to keep only the columns containing exactly your key.

**Edit:** You don't need a `CHARINDEX` specification too.